# Combine 3 level multi dimensional array according to index

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array.in which i want to combine value according to same index value of sub array.it's a multi dimensional dynamic array which contain some same and some different indexes like sports footer etc.Please check the below array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Sport] => 15
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Sport] => 14
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [Sport] => 29
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Surgical] => 11
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Surgical] => 12
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [Surgical] => 13
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [Footwear] => 10
                )

        )

)
```

Below it the array format which i want as an output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array 
        (
            [0] => 15
            [1]  => 14
            [2]  => 29


        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11
            [1]  => 12
            [2]  => 13


        ),
    [2] => Array(
            [0] => 10
    )

)
```

Comment: Have You Tried Anything to get the desire output? If yes, Please feel free to share your tried code.

Comment: $key='';
   for ($i=0; $i<count($prodbyTax); $i++){
    
    for ($j = 0; $j< count($prodbyTax[$i]); $j++){
     
     foreach($prodbyTax[$i][$j] as $key => $val){
      
      if($prevKey==''|| $key == $prevKey){
       echo "if <br/>";
       $testing[] = $val;
       $prevKey = $key;
      }else{
       echo "else <br/>";
       $testing1[] = $val;
       $prevKey='';
      }
      
     }
     
    }
    
   }
this is my code but i want to combine value of same indexs, like sports values must be in one array same for surgical and  other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your input array is called `$data`, you could do this:

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $pair) {
        foreach ($pair as $key => $value) {
            $result[$key][] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

This will provide the `$result` as follows:

```
[
    "Sport" => [15, 14, 29],
    "Surgical" => [11, 12, 13],
    "Footwear" => [10]
]
```

If you really want to throw away the "labels" and just keep the values, then add the following conversion at the end:

```
$result = array_values($result);
```

Which will give you the desired result:

```
[
    [15, 14, 29],
    [11, 12, 13],
    [10]
]
```

... but that would seem less useful to me.